# Changing Project Build Configuration to Debug mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, configurationmanager

I am using VS 2008. I am getting a PopUp everytime i run my application.

Following is the PopUp:

> The following module was built with
>   optimizations enabled or without debug
>   information :
>
> ```
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7c06d97f\c871fca3\assembly\dl3\1ed1f335\00d7b454_9450ca01\BArcodingImaging.DLL
> ```
>
> To debug this module, change its
>   project build configuration to debug
>   mode. To suppress this message,
>   disable the "Warn inf no user code on
>   launch" debugger option.

I have tried all the links available on the Google to get rid of this error but nothing works. Actually most of the links are for VS 2005. But i am using VS 2008.

I used following reference:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/1946cf16-ae70-4394-9cd9-9d35f3f012ed/
And one on Code Guru.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

1) Click on the menu `Tools > Settings` and select `Expert Settings`
2) A new menu called `Build` has appeared. In it, select `Configuration manager`
3) In `Active solution configuration`, click `New...` as shown below:

[image]

4) Type `Debug` as a name and select to copy from `Release`, as shown below:

[image]

5) In your project's properties, at the top of the `Build` tab, a configuration selector has now appeared. Mark the `Define DEBUG constant` and `Define TRACE constant` as checked. In `Advanced`, change `Debug Info` from `none` to `full`.

As you see, it is a real pain... I find [Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com) much easier to use.

Answer (score 8):

It seem that in my configuration all have been set correct with debug ON, but I have too this problem. It is fix with this steps:

1. Stop my local IIS
2. Close all visual studios
3. Check directory cache from your message when start to debug
4. delete this directory
   For was this path:
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\eventsservice\5d285bc1
5. Start again your IIS
6. Rebuild projects, solutions
   Done!

The problem may be because in your solution have project with the different framework version.
Check this too and set it correctly. All project that are reference between must use the same framework version.

Answer (score 3):

This one caught me out, and having learnt Visual Studio the hard way (ie: just diving in) it wasn't clear how to change the 'Active' build configuration to 'Debug'.  This can be done by selecting `Configuration Manager` from the `Build` Menu and then selecting 'Debug' from the Active solution configuration pulldown menu.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the message.

The solution (that works for me) was simple:

Go to Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General

At this point, unselect 'Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)'.

Attach the process again, and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, when having the service being installed under account Local System I could debug without ever needing to change anything. I needed to change the account to Network Service and now I have the mentioned dialog. Tried above, none worked...

Comment: did you discover the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've resolve with disable Enable Just my code options in visual studio 2019 debugging options
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  I am not using vs 2008 , but with vs 2010 sp1 , I re-opened and it worked  (I feel I got lucky).

Long Answer:
 I'm using vs 2010 sp1 , and tried several things, I was going to delete the dll from my path error C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2c0d3658\caacfa0a\assembly\dl3\53e39126\e888ca9f_7252cc01 INSTEAD I SHUTDOWN visual studio and IIS EXPRESS I stopped .... Then I re-opened the project and things were fine. I thought I have a 10-25% chance of it fixing itself... but it fixed itself just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem was caused by the incorrect setting about debugging in VS2012. I ever carelessly unchecked the checkbox "Always load symbols located next to modules, then I got the same Popup message box like your picture.

the checkbox location: TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols->Specify modules.

I give a picture below to show how to resolve it, hope it will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clear the dll from the GAC. Do a rebuild and try again.
I was getting the exact message (except for the actual dll name ) so I checked where the dll was built to and compared this path to the path in the 'Driver' or Caller app. Then I removed the dll from the GAC did a rebuild and set appropriate breakpoints.  VS doesn't automatically update the version number on the dll so it was looking for a different version to the one I was debugging.